# Angular service observable to return nested array data

Tags: arrays, json, angular, observable

My endpoint contains like this

```
{
        'dsco_st_license': {
            'ttco_st_license': [
                {
                    'csl_state': 'AK',
                    'csl_license_name': 'Specialty Contractor',
                    'csl_license_code': 'Communications',
                    'csl_license_number': '123456'
                },
                {
                    'csl_state': 'AL',
                    'csl_license_name': '',
                    'csl_license_code': '',
                    'csl_license_number': 'Not Required'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

and here is my service

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._WebLicenseServiceService.getWebLicensesHttpCall()
        .subscribe(data => this.weblicenses = data,
        err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
        () => console.log('close loading spinner')
    );

    console.log(this.weblicenses);
}
```

when i console.log(this.weblicenses);
it dosnt contain the data. Instead looks like this

```
[]length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
```

I also tried

console.log(this.weblicenses['dsco_st_license']['dsco_st_license']);

But this errors out because of my interface

```
export interface IWeblicense {
csl_state: string;
csl_license_name: string;
csl_license_code: string;
csl_license_number: string;
```

}

How can I get the ttco_st_license to be returned?

Comment: You're logging before you get the data. Move the logging into the `subscribe`.

Comment: You are console.logging outside of the subscribe.  Therefore the console.log will be executed long before the subscribe completes with your data.  Move the console.log into the anonymous function of your subscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the response data inside subscribe function which ensure it will be executed once the response is completed.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._WebLicenseServiceService.getWebLicensesHttpCall()
        .subscribe(data => {
           this.weblicenses = data;
           console.log(this.weblicenses); //<--- Get the data after call completes.
           console.log(this.weblicenses.dsco_st_license. ttco_st_license); //<---ttco_st_license
         },
        err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
        () => console.log('close loading spinner')
    );

    // console.log(this.weblicenses); //<-- Remove this since it will return undefined
}
```