# Working with multiple nested subscriptions in sequence (Angular, RxJs)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I need to construct a nested object from the result of three Observable streams and display the . All three observables return an array, and two depend on the result of the first. The code I have is as follows:

```
this.selectActiveFoos$.pipe(
  concatMap(foos => {
    return foos.map(foo => {
      let bars$ = this.barQuery.selectBarsByFooId(foo.id);  
      let bazs$ = this.bazQuery.selectBazsByFooId(foo.id); // these observables return Observable<T[]>
      return forkJoin([bars$, bazs$]).pipe(
        map(([bars, bazs]) => {
          return { 
            foo: foo,
            bars: bars,
            bazs: bazs
          }
        })
      );
    });
  })).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

}

IntelliSense tells me that the type of result is as expected, i.e. a

```
{ foo: foo, bars: bar[], bazs: baz[] }
```

however, the console logs an observable as an output. This is really throwing me for a loop. I've searched online for quite some time but I can't seem to find an answer that works with nested arrays of Observable<T[]>.

I would appreciate any advice!

Comment: is it something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344876/angular-service-observable-to-return-nested-array-data

Comment: You're possibly returning `[forkJoin(), forkJoin(),..]` for each element of the `foos` array. You need to show what is the structure of that array and how each observable to the `forkJoin` should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concatMap must receive an Observable, you can use forkJoin:

```
this.selectActiveFoos$.pipe(
  concatMap(foos => {
    return forkJoin(foos.map(foo => {
      let bars$ = this.barQuery.selectBarsByFooId(foo.id);  
      let bazs$ = this.bazQuery.selectBazsByFooId(foo.id); // these observables return Observable<T[]>
      return forkJoin([bars$, bazs$]).pipe(
        map(([bars, bazs]) => {
          return { 
            foo: foo,
            bars: bars,
            bazs: bazs
          }
        })
      );
    }));
  })).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. If concatMap must receive an observable, why doesn't it show a compile time error?

Comment: @E.Mumford accept the answer if it works. what version of typescript and rxjs do you have?

Comment: my mistake. First question :) Typescript is ~3.7.5 and RxJs is ~6.5.4